# Bounding the variance.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let, $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be independent random variables, where $X_j$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p_j \in [0,1]$.
Let, $g(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ be a function, satisfying the bounded difference condition with constants $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n > 0$.

I am trying to show that  $$Var(g(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)) \leq \sum_{j=1}^n c_j^2p_j(1-p_j)$$
where$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be independent random variables, $X_j$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p_j \in [0,1]$. The function $g(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ satisfies bounded difference condition with constants $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n > 0$.

---

I know that if the random variables satisfy Bounded Difference Condition; the following holds true $$|g(x_1,\dots, x_{j-1},x_j,x_{j+1}, \dots, x_n) - g(x_1,\dots, x_{j-1},x_j',x_{j+1}, \dots, x_n)| \leq c_j$$ where $x_j'$ is an independent copy of $x_j$. Under this condition one can also show that $Var(g(x_1,\dots,x_n)) \leq \frac{1}{4} \sum_{j=1}^nc_j^2$. Furthermore, by Efron-Stein inequality, $$Var(g(x_1,\dots,x_n)) \leq \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}\sum_{j=1}^n\bigg( g(x_1,\dots,x_j,\dots ,x_n) - g(x_1,\dots,x_j',\dots ,x_n)\bigg)^2$$
From the BDC above this inequality becomes; $$Var(g(x_1,\dots,x_n)) \leq \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}\sum_{j=1}^nc_j^2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n c_j^2$$
I am still missing the factor $p_j(1-p_j)$ which is basically $Var(X_j)$. But I am not sure how to incorporate this term.
Can anyone please drop a hint on how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a step from
$$Var(g(X_1,\dots,X_n)) \leq \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}\sum_{j=1}^n\bigg( g(X_1,\dots,X_j,\dots ,X_n) - g(X_1,\dots,X_j',\dots ,X_n)\bigg)^2$$

For every $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$, we have
$$\begin{align}
L&:=\mathbb{E}\bigg( \left|g(X_1,\dots,X_j,\dots ,X_n) - g(X_1,\dots,X_j',\dots ,X_n)\right|^2\bigg)\\
&=p_j^2\mathbb{E}\left(\left|g(X_1,..,1,...,X_n) - g(X_1,..,1,...,X_n)\right|^2\right)\\
&+(1-p_j)^2\mathbb{E}\left(\left|(g(X_1,..,0,...,X_n) - g(X_1,..,0,...,X_n)\right|^2\right)\\
&+p_j(1-p_j)\mathbb{E}\left(\left|(g(X_1,..,1,...,X_n) - g(X_1,..,0,...,X_n)\right|^2\right)\\
&+p_j(1-p_j)\mathbb{E}\left(\left|(g(X_1,..,0,...,X_n) - g(X_1,..,1,...,X_n)\right|^2\right)\\
&=2p_j(1-p_j)\mathbb{E}\left(\left|(g(X_1,..,0,...,X_n) - g(X_1,..,1,...,X_n)\right|^2\right) \le 2p_j(1-p_j)c_j^2
\end{align}$$

From that, you deduce easily your final result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Before you apply the BDC, argue for each $j$
$$\begin{align}
&\left(g(X_1,\ldots,X_j,\ldots,X_n)-g(X_1,\ldots,X'_j,\ldots,X_n)\right)^2\\
&\qquad=\left(g(X_1,\ldots,X_j,\ldots,X_n)-g(X_1,\ldots,X'_j,\ldots,X_n)\right)^2I(X_j\ne X'_j).
\end{align}
$$